# Maven http.authentication.preemptive against Artifactory

Tags: maven-3, artifactory

I am having enormous difficulty downloading "protected" artifacts from my Artifactory server.  Can anyone confirm that the (maven) settings.xml excerpt below is sufficient to cause GET requests to carry authentication info preemptively?

Maven 3.3.9.  Artifactory 4.4.2.

```
<servers>
<server>
  <id>myServerId</id>
  <username>myUserId</username> 
  <password>myPlainTextPassword</password>
  <configuration>
     <httpConfiguration>
        <all>
           <params>
              <property>
                 <name>http.authentication.preemptive</name>
                 <value>%b,true</value>
              </property>
           </params>
        </all>
     </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
</server>
</servers>
```

Thanks,

Robin

Maven output:

```
C:\>mvn -U clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building fc 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.myserver.co.uk/artifactory/libs-release/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom
Downloading: http://www.license4j.com/maven/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom
Downloading: http://repo.myserver.co.uk/artifactory/private-local/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.906 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-31T19:41:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project fc: Could not resolve dependencies for project uk.co.myserver:fc:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.group:artifact:jar:126: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.group:artifact:jar:126: Could not transfer artifact com.group:artifact:pom:126 from/to releases (http://repo.myserver.co.uk/artifactory/libs-release): Access denied to: http://repo.myserver.co.uk/artifactory/libs-release/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Artifactory Access Log:

```
2016-02-01 11:14:33,562 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] libs-release:com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom for anonymous/193.66.174.253.
2016-02-01 11:14:33,564 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] private-release-local:com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom for anonymous/193.66.174.253.
2016-02-01 11:14:34,436 [ACCEPTED DELETE] libs-release:com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom for anonymous/193.66.174.253.
2016-02-01 11:14:35,010 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] private-local:com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom for anonymous/193.66.174.253.
2016-02-01 11:14:35,011 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] private-release-local:com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom for anonymous/193.66.174.253.
2016-02-01 11:14:35,012 [ACCEPTED DELETE] private-local:com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom for anonymous/193.66.174.253.
```

All of the below exist identically in pom.xml and in settings.xml and, since they all reference the same Artifactory server, they share identical username/password/http.authentication.preemptive parameters :

```
<id>releases</id>
<id>snapshots</id>
<id>private-local</id>
<id>plugin-releases</id>
<id>plugin-snapshots</id>
<id>deploy-releases</id>
<id>deploy-snapshots</id>
```

Only the below is not mentioned in settings.xml, as access should be anonymous and it is a separate repository instance on someone else's server:

```
<id>license4j-runtime-library</id>
```

Here is the corresponding output from the request log:

```
20160202060102|58|REQUEST|193.66.174.253|admin|GET|/ui/systemlogs/logData|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20160202060102|1099|REQUEST|199.19.249.196|anonymous|GET|/libs-release/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20160202060102|706|REQUEST|199.91.135.165|anonymous|GET|/libs-release/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20160202060102|5|REQUEST|193.66.174.253|anonymous|GET|/libs-release/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20160202060103|3|REQUEST|199.19.249.196|anonymous|GET|/private-local/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20160202060103|3|REQUEST|193.66.174.253|anonymous|GET|/private-local/com/group/artifact/126/artifact-126.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|0
20160202060113|60|REQUEST|193.66.174.253|admin|GET|/ui/systemlogs/logData|HTTP/1.1|200|0
```

Note that there are two requests to private-local, both of which occur as "anonymous".  With preemptive authentication I would have expected all of these to have been  as "myUserId".

Comment: Provide the log output.

Comment: Justtrying to work out how to attach the log excerpt....

Comment: Make sure the server `<id/>` matches the one of `<repositories/>`, `<pluginRepositories/>` and the ones used for both repositories in your `<distributionManagement/>`. Otherwise, the credentials you've specified above will not be used. If you have a `<mirrors/>` section in your `settings.xml`, you need to make sure the `<id/>` there also matches, as well as any `<repositories/>` and `<pluginRepositories/>` defined in there as a profile.

Comment: All of the below exist identically in pom.xml and in settings.xml and, since they all reference the same Artifactory server, they share identical username/password/http.authentication.preemptive parameters : 

    <id>releases</id>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <id>private-local</id>
    <id>plugin-releases</id>
    <id>plugin-snapshots</id>
    <id>deploy-releases</id>
    <id>deploy-snapshots</id>

Only the below is not mentioned in settings.xml, as access should be anonymous and it is a separate repository instance on someone else's server:

<id>license4j-runtime-library</id>

Comment: For reference, my mvn command is executed from behind an AUTHENTICATED http proxy.

Comment: Attach your `settings.xml` and `pom.xml` files, please.

Answer (score 1):

What are the permissions that you have for your anonymous user on Artifactory?

On Artifactory --> Admin --> Security --> General --> Is the checkbox for "Hide existence of unauthorised resources" is checked?

Other than that can you also paste the relevant part from the request.log?

Comment: I've been round the houses on these, but currently: AllowAnonymousAccess=TRUE, HideExistanceOfUnauthorizedResources=FALSE.

Comment: As far as permissions are concerned ANONYMOUS has READ + DEPLOY/CACHE privilege to ANY REMOTE. ANONYMOUS has READ privilege to a separate permission target containing most LOCAL repositories, but not including repository "private-release-local".

Comment: Local repository "private-release-local" is the only repository in the virtual repository "private-local".

Comment: Request log excerpt has been appended to the original question.  All requests appear as 'anonymous'.

Comment: In the request.log you can see that the response is 401. That means that Maven should get challenged and send the credentials from the settings.xml. In case that Maven doesn't send the credentials you should check that you have defined credentials for the profile in use.

Comment: You can also try and generate settings.xml from Artifactory with your user, and try using those settings.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Filtered+Resources#FilteredResources-ProvisioningBuildToolSettings

Comment: I am not using any specific profile.  One is defined, "sonar", but it is not activated.  The server details are not profile-specific, i.e. they are not defined within a "profile" element.

Comment: I'll try to sum things up a bit so we will be aligned:
Normal process:
1. Maven try to resolve artifacts from Artifactory.
2. The desired artifacts are in private repositories which the anonymous don't have access to.
3. Artifactory will return 401 to the maven client.
4. Maven gets the 401 = challenge.
5. Maven send the credentials that are defined to that profile.
6. Artifactory allow the client to get the artifacts. 

Your case:

Comment: Your case:
1. Maven try to resolve artifacts from Artifactory.
2. The desired artifacts are in private repositories which the anonymous don't have access to.
3. Artifactory will return 401 to the maven client. (can see in the request.log)
4. Maven gets the 401 but doesn't reply with the credentials.
I believe that the issue is related to the settings.xml / pom.xml that are not providing the credentials after the the initial challenge.
Can you try to generate new settings via Artifactory as I explained in previous comment and retry? This should assist in narrow down the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

When going behind a proxy the httpConfiguration for the server must be:

```
<server>
    <id>**********</id>
    <username>**********</username>
    <password>**********</password>
    <configuration>
        <httpConfiguration>
          <all>
            <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
          </all>
        </httpConfiguration>
    </configuration>
</server>
```